# Regular polygon with $n$ sides , the number of triangles

Tags: combinatorics, polygons

> For a regular polygon with $n$ sides $(n>5)$, the number of triangles whose vertices are joining non-adjacent vertices of the polygon is $n(n-4)(n-5)$.

When I take $n=6$, I get David's Star:

[image: David's star:]

So, only two triangles! How can I get $n(n-4)(n-5)$?

Comment: The formula I know of for number of triangles is $n(n-4)(n-5)/6$, what is the source of the original statement?

Comment: Ok, so there might be mistake in my book, which is high school level problem book. Can you please explain how is $n(n-4)(n-5)/6$ derived?

Comment: Got it [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/364151/number-of-triangles-in-a-regular-polygon)!